# Solving $\sqrt{2}=\frac{\cos(x)}{\cos(2x)}$

Tags: trigonometry

How can I solve $$\sqrt{2}=\frac{\cos(x)}{\cos(2x)}$$
for $0\leq{x}\leq{2\pi}$?
I can't find any trigonometric identity to solve it.

Comment: @user222031 That is not an identity. You are confusing with $\sin(2x)$

Comment: look up "double angle formulas", they are very useful

Comment: *I can't find any trigonometric identity*, really ?! Have you even tried, I don't know... The one for $\cos(2x)$ for instance.

Comment: @ZubinMukerjee I know. I'm very stupid sometimes...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have cosine of sum: $$\cos(A+B) = \cos A \cos B - \sin A \sin B$$

Letting $A=B=x$ gives the double angle formula for cosine: $$\cos(2x) = \cos^2(x) - \sin^2(x)$$

Using the fact that $\sin^2(x)+\cos^2(x)=1$, write $\sin^2(x) = 1-\cos^2(x)$ to give: $$\cos(2x) = \cos^2(x) - [1 - \cos^2(X)] = 2\cos^2(x)-1$$

Then, your equation becomes: $$\sqrt2 = \frac{\cos(x)}{2\cos^2(x)-1}$$

Rearranging gives: $$2\sqrt2\cos^2(x) - \cos(x) - \sqrt2 = 0$$

Let $y=\cos(x)$. Then: $$2\sqrt2 y^2 - y - \sqrt2=0$$

which is a quadratic equation that you hopefully can solve.